# listing directories having "-" character in directories name

Tags: python-2.7

I want to list the directories in current directory having "-" character in directories name. I used os.listdir(path). Its giving me error :

> "WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume
>   label syntax is incorrect:"

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: A little difficult to answer without a sample of your code. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) to get directory contents and then filter using [`os.path.isdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) to check if each item is a dir:

```
dirs_with_hyphen = []
for thing in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if os.path.isdir(thing) and '-' in thing:
        dirs_with_hyphen.append(thing)

print dirs_with_hyphen # or return, etc.
```

And that can be shortened using list comprehension:

```
dirs_with_hyphen = [thing for thing in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if os.path.isdir(thing) and '-' in thing]
```

I'm using [`os.getcwd`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd) but you could pass in any string that represents a folder.

If you're getting an error about the filename being incorrect, you're probably not escaping correctly or it's not pointing to the right folder (absolute vs relative path issue).

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing and I managed to get your error. I don't know if this is what you did to get the error though since no example has been provided.

What I did though is give an invalid drive path. Not one that could be valid and doesn't exist, one that is always wrong eg.`'C::\'` or `'CC:\'` just anything that's not `'C:\'`. As for your question.

Path should generally look like this, prefixing with `r` to ignore backslash as escape character or double backslash.

```
import os

path = r"C:\Users\Steven\Documents\"
path = "C:\\Users\\Steven\\Documents\"

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isdir(path+file) and '-' in file:
        print path + file

#List Comp
[path+file for file in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(path+file) and '-' in file]
```